What's the best way to structure my targets for a Multiplatform VisionOS and MacOS application
I currently have an application for VisionOS written with Metal but I want to also support MacOS.
So far it the application is just
MyApp (Project)
    MyApp (Target)

If I add MacOS to the existing target, the MacOS part doesn't build because I have a RealityKitContent package. I also have a bunch of metal and header code that requires a bridging header. I'm not sure how to fix the RealityKitContent build issue, or if I can or do I need to separate out my targets like this
MyApp (Project)
    VisionOS (Target)
    MacOS (Target)
    Common (Target)

The problem I'm having with this approach is that the Common needs to hold the Metal code but as a "multi-platform framework" it doesn't seem to support bridging headers.
